# Finding highest parent in a tree structure

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have a tree structure that is made out of the data below. I need a search algorithm to find the top leader when I put in anyone's `_id` value, regardless of leader or child.

For example, if the input is `"615e8215c3055d1addc216b0"` (the id of Rahman) or `"61164b4bc08f86505e7dcdd8"` (the id of Aaron Aziz) it should return the id of "Aaron Aziz" as he is the leader.

[image: The Tree Structure]

The data structure has essentially a 2 level structure where each top-level entry has references to its immediate children. Notice that a child may appear again as leader (at the top level) so to specify deeper connections:

```
"families": [
        {
            "datecreated": "2021-10-06T07:39:28.988Z",
            "_id": "615d52cb7cc6d32978afa694",
            "leader": {
                "_id": "61164b4bc08f86505e7dcdd8",
                "name": "Aaron Aziz"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "datejoined": "2021-10-06T07:39:28.988Z",
                    "_id": "615d52cb7cc6d32978afa695",
                    "child": {
                        "_id": "615c15c66dd91a2d4385ac84",
                        "name": "Amirul Adha"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "datejoined": "2021-10-06T08:04:52.122Z",
                    "_id": "615d58cf0f045f320cb28706",
                    "child": {
                        "_id": "615d58b40f045f320cb28701",
                        "name": "Samirul Ali"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "datecreated": "2021-10-07T05:12:22.671Z",
            "_id": "615e8475c3055d1addc216b5",
            "leader": {
                "_id": "615c15c66dd91a2d4385ac84",
                "name": "Amirul Adha"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "datejoined": "2021-10-07T05:12:22.671Z",
                    "_id": "615e8475c3055d1addc216b6",
                    "child": {
                        "_id": "615e8215c3055d1addc216b0",
                        "name": "Rahman"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "datecreated": "2021-10-07T08:52:47.840Z",
            "_id": "615eb630e0cc0d22281bb282",
            "leader": {
                "_id": "615e8215c3055d1addc216b0",
                "name": "Rahman"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "datejoined": "2021-10-07T08:52:47.840Z",
                    "_id": "615eb630e0cc0d22281bb283",
                    "child": {
                        "_id": "615eb60de0cc0d22281bb27d",
                        "name": "Aizi"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I've created a recursive function. But when I input a child without children, it returns the sibling instead of the parent.

```
  const findLeader = (childId) => {
    let leader;
    for (const family of familiesCopy) {
      const isChild = family.children.find((i) => i.child._id == childId);
      leader = family.leader;
      if (isChild) {
        findLeader(family.leader._id);
      }
      if (!isChild) {
        return leader;
      }
    }
    return leader;
  };
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a function to first transform the structure, so each person can be looked up by id in constant time, giving their leader reference, children references and other properties.

So here is a `makeGraph` function to do just that, and then `getTopLeader` function to search that graph for a given child:

```js
function makeGraph(families) {
    // Collect children and key by their id
    let graph = Object.fromEntries(families.flatMap(({ leader: { _id }, children }) =>
        children.map(({ child, ...relation }) => [child._id, {
            ...child,
            leader: _id,
            relation,
            children: [],
        }])
    ));
    // Collect leaders and key by their id, possibly extending existing entry
    for (let { leader, children, ...creation } of families) {
        Object.assign(graph[leader._id] ??= {}, {
            ...leader,
            creation,
            children: children.map(({child}) => child._id)
        });
    }
    return graph;
}

function getTopLeader(graph, id) {
    if (!graph[id]) return; // Not found
    while (graph[id].leader) id = graph[id].leader;
    return id;
}

// Example run on question's data
let obj = {"families": [{"datecreated": "2021-10-06T07:39:28.988Z","_id": "615d52cb7cc6d32978afa694","leader": {"_id": "61164b4bc08f86505e7dcdd8","name": "Aaron Aziz"},"children": [{"datejoined": "2021-10-06T07:39:28.988Z","_id": "615d52cb7cc6d32978afa695","child": {"_id": "615c15c66dd91a2d4385ac84","name": "Amirul Adha"}},{"datejoined": "2021-10-06T08:04:52.122Z","_id": "615d58cf0f045f320cb28706","child": {"_id": "615d58b40f045f320cb28701","name": "Samirul Ali"}}]},{"datecreated": "2021-10-07T05:12:22.671Z","_id": "615e8475c3055d1addc216b5","leader": {"_id": "615c15c66dd91a2d4385ac84","name": "Amirul Adha"},"children": [{"datejoined": "2021-10-07T05:12:22.671Z","_id": "615e8475c3055d1addc216b6","child": {"_id": "615e8215c3055d1addc216b0","name": "Rahman"}}]},{"datecreated": "2021-10-07T08:52:47.840Z","_id": "615eb630e0cc0d22281bb282","leader": {"_id": "615e8215c3055d1addc216b0","name": "Rahman"},"children": [{"datejoined": "2021-10-07T08:52:47.840Z","_id": "615eb630e0cc0d22281bb283","child": {"_id": "615eb60de0cc0d22281bb27d","name": "Aizi"}}]}]};
let graph = makeGraph(obj.families);
let childid = "615e8215c3055d1addc216b0"; // Rahman
let leaderid = getTopLeader(graph, childid); // 61164b4bc08f86505e7dcdd8 = Aaron Aziz

console.log(`Leader of ${childid} is ${leaderid}`);
```

The `graph` variable will be useful for other lookup tasks as well.

Comment: I've coded a solution but this is really clean and i've learned alot from your answer. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since you always want the first entry, you can use something like families[0] to access it. You won't need a search algorithm:

```
x = {your json data}
x["families"][0]["leader"]["name"]
```

Output:

```
'Aaron Aziz'
```

Comment: It has to be a recursive function. For example if the input is  "_id": "615eb60de0cc0d22281bb27d" ("Aizi"). Who is a child of Rahman, Who is a child of Amirul Adha, Who is a child of Aaron Aziz

Comment: @FarisMalik If you have certain requirements, they should be specified in the question.